# firestore onsnapshot listner not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am trying to listen to new chat messages (when someone or I add new chat message) like below. but its not listening to live queries. Please help me to sort it ...

```
async componentDidMount() {
 this.getChatTexts();
}

async getChatTexts() {
    if (this.state.tripId) {
      firestore()
        .collection('Chats')
        .where('tripId', '==', this.state.tripId)
        .orderBy('time', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot({includeMetadataChanges: true}, snapshot => {
          if (snapshot) {
            this.setState({chatWindow: true});
            var chatmessages = [];
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach(e => {
              chatmessages.push(e.doc.data());
            });
            this.setState({chatMessages: chatmessages});
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: You marked componentDidMount as 'async' and called another async method, but didn't 'await' the response.   Maybe you meant to put an 'await' before the call to getChatTexts()?

Comment: @msenne yes I have some other async plan there after I sort out this issue :)

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?